# ExceptionNotifier and rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, error-handling

I am trying to implement exception_notifier and a custom exception handling
in my rails 3 app. When I am only using exception notifier everything works fine.
In development mode with

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

and a rescue_from in my application_controller:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error
end

def render_error(exception)
  ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(request.env, exception).deliver
end
```

in my application.rb

```
config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email_prefix => "Error: ",
  :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@wannagohome.com>},
  :exception_recipients => %w{ myself@fail.com }
```

The only problem seems to be, that the options are not loaded into the request.env.
I tried the file in a extra initializer and I don't know what else - it's not working.
At the moment I have a really ugly hack, where I merge the request.env with a 
hash before delivering the email..
Any idea?

Comment: Do you ever find a solution to this problem? I have it too so any help you can provide is great appreciated!

Comment: Nope, I had to hijack the request.env and set them manually

Comment: Could you post an example of how you did that? Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

exception_notification is middleware in Rails 3 so the options are set directly on the class that processes the call and that class doesn't set them in the environment unless it catches an exception ([see here](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification/blob/master/lib/exception_notifier.rb)). [This fork](https://github.com/sunkencity/exception_notification) adds a background_exception_notification method that you can use. I borrowed the idea and just added this helper method:

```
def background_exception_notification(env, exception)
  if notifier = Rails.application.config.middleware.detect { |x| x.klass == ExceptionNotifier }
    env['exception_notifier.options'] = notifier.args.first || {}                   
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(env, exception).deliver
    env['exception_notifier.delivered'] = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered issuing a pull request to the official repo (nowadays https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification)?